# MySQL "incorrect string value" error when save unicode string in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, utf-8

I got strange error message when tried to save first_name, last_name to Django's auth_user model.

**Failed examples**

```
user = User.object.create_user(username, email, password)
user.first_name = u'Rytis'
user.last_name = u'Slatkevičius'
user.save()
>>> Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x8Dius' for column 'last_name' at row 104

user.first_name = u'Валерий'
user.last_name = u'Богданов'
user.save()
>>> Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x92\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBB...' for column 'first_name' at row 104

user.first_name = u'Krzysztof'
user.last_name = u'Szukiełojć'
user.save()
>>> Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x82oj\xC4\x87' for column 'last_name' at row 104
```

**Succeed examples**

```
user.first_name = u'Marcin'
user.last_name = u'Król'
user.save()
>>> SUCCEED
```

**MySQL settings**

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_connection | utf8                       | 
| character_set_database   | utf8                       | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | utf8                       | 
| character_set_server     | utf8                       | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Table charset and collation**

Table auth_user has utf-8 charset with utf8_general_ci collation.

**Results of UPDATE command**

It didn't raise any error when updating above values to auth_user table by using UPDATE command.

```
mysql> update auth_user set last_name='Slatkevičiusa' where id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select last_name from auth_user where id=100;
+---------------+
| last_name     |
+---------------+
| Slatkevi?iusa | 
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**PostgreSQL**

The failed values listed above can be updated into PostgreSQL table when I switched the database backend in Django. It's strange.

```
mysql> SHOW CHARACTER SET;
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+--------+
| Charset  | Description                 | Default collation   | Maxlen |
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+--------+
...
| utf8     | UTF-8 Unicode               | utf8_general_ci     |      3 | 
...
```

But from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/multibyte.html, I found the following:

```
Name Bytes/Char
UTF8 1-4
```

Is it means unicode char has maxlen of 4 bytes in PostgreSQL but 3 bytes in MySQL which caused above error?

Comment: It's a MySQL problem, not Django: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured out one method to avoid above errors.

**Save to database**

```
user.first_name = u'Rytis'.encode('unicode_escape')
user.last_name = u'Slatkevičius'.encode('unicode_escape')
user.save()
>>> SUCCEED

print user.last_name
>>> Slatkevi\u010dius
print user.last_name.decode('unicode_escape')
>>> Slatkevičius
```

Is this the only method to save strings like that into a MySQL table and decode it before rendering to templates for display?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but I don't agree that this is a valid solution.  When you `.encode('unicode_escape')` you're not actually storing unicode characters in the database.  You're forcing all the clients to unencode before using them, which means it won't work properly with django.admin or all sorts of other things.

Comment: While it seems distasteful to store escape codes instead of characters, this is probably one of the few ways to save 4-byte UTF-8 characters such as emoji in MySQL 5.1's 3-byte `utf8` character set.

Comment: There is an encoding called `utf8mb4` that allows more than the Basic Multilingual Plane to be stored. I know, you'd think "UTF8" is all that's needed to store Unicode fully. Well, whaddaya know, it's not. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: @jack you might want to consider changing the accepted answer to one which is more useful

Comment: it is a feasible workaround, but I do not recommend using it too (as advocated by @muudscope). I still can't store, for example, emoji to mysql databases. Has anybody accomplished it?

Comment: Fantastic, took me ages to find this.

Answer (score 172):

None of these answers solved the problem for me. The root cause being:

**You cannot store 4-byte characters in MySQL with the utf-8 character set.**

MySQL has a [3 byte limit on utf-8 characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) (yes, it's wack, [nicely summed up by a Django developer here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18392#comment:16))

To solve this you need to:

1. Change your MySQL database, table and columns to use the [utf8mb4 character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) (only available from MySQL 5.5 onwards)
2. Specify the charset in your Django settings file as below:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
    }
}
```

Note: When recreating your database you may run into the '[Specified key was too long](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21308)' issue.

The most likely cause is a `CharField` which has a max_length of 255 and some kind of index on it (e.g. unique). Because utf8mb4 uses 33% more space than utf-8 you'll need to make these fields 33% smaller.

In this case, change the max_length from 255 to 191.

Alternatively you can [edit your MySQL configuration to remove this restriction](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18392#comment:19) *but not without some django hackery*

**UPDATE:** I just ran into this issue again and ended up [switching to PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) because I was unable to reduce my `VARCHAR` to 191 characters.

Comment: this answer needs way, way, way more upvotes. Thanks! The real problem is your application may run fine for years until someone tries to enter a 4byte character.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. The OPTIONS setting is critical to make django decode emoji characters and store them in MySQL. Just changing mysql charset to utf8mb4 via SQL commands is not enough!

Comment: There's no need to update the character set of the whole table to utf8mb4. Just update character set of necessary columns. Also the `'charset': 'utf8mb4'` option in Django settings is critical, as @Xerion said. Finally, the index problem is a mess. Remove the index on the column, or make its length no more than 191, or use a `TextField` instead!

Comment: I love your [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18392#comment:16) to this quote: _This is just another case of MySQL being purposefully and irreversibly brain-damaged._ :)

Comment: Note that if using `mysql.connector.django` as the database backend, you must also set `'collation': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'` in `OPTIONS`.

Comment: It helped me, also I needed to change it in MySQL:  ALTER TABLE <<table_name>>  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' Which also required me to limit size of certain columns. But it worked. Yeee

Comment: + `ALTER TABLE group_history CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` as described here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51198483]

Answer (score 127):

I had the same problem and resolved it by changing the character set of the column. Even though your database has a default character set of `utf-8` I think it's possible for database columns to have a different character set in MySQL. Here's the SQL QUERY I used:

```
    ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)
    CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Ugh, I changed all the character sets on everything I could until I really re-read this answer: *columns* can have their *own* character sets, independent of the tables and the database. That's crazy and also was exactly my problem.

Comment: This worked for me as well, using mysql with the defaults, in a TextField model.

Comment: This solved my problem. The only change I did was to use utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_general_ci instead of utf8 / utf8_general_ci.

Answer (score 72):

If you have this problem here's a python script to change all the columns of your mysql database automatically.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb

host = "localhost"
passwd = "passwd"
user = "youruser"
dbname = "yourdbname"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=dbname)
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("ALTER DATABASE `%s` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'" % dbname)

sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(table_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '%s'" % dbname
cursor.execute(sql)

results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
  sql = "ALTER TABLE `%s` convert to character set DEFAULT COLLATE DEFAULT" % (row[0])
  cursor.execute(sql)
db.close()
```

Comment: This solution solved all my issues with a django app which was storing file and directory paths.  Toss in dbname as your django database and let it run.  Worked like a charm!

Comment: This code didn't work for me until I added `db.commit()` before `db.close()`.

Comment: Does this solution avoid the issue discussed in @markpasc comment: '...4-byte UTF-8 characters such as emoji in MySQL 5.1's 3-byte utf8 character set'

Comment: the solution help me when i was deleting a record trough django admin, i didn't had any problem when creating o editing...weird! I was even able to delete directly in the db

Comment: Should I do this every time I change the Model?

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't this use `utf8mb4` if it is supposed to solve the original problem?

Answer (score 28):

If it's a new project, I'd just drop the database, and create a new one with a proper charset:

```
CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Hi  kindly help check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348817/django-polls-with-autentication?noredirect=1#comment79739118_46348817

Comment: In my case, our db is created by docker so to fix I added the following to the db:command: instruction in my compose file: `- --character-set-server=utf8`

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks @Vanuan

Comment: if this is not a new project, we get backup from db, drop it and recreate it with utf8 charset and then restore backup. I did it in my project that was not new...

Comment: @followben thank you, that resolved my problem. Though I had to use `--character-set-server=utf8mb4`

Answer (score 6):

You can change the collation of your text field to UTF8_general_ci and the problem will be solved.

Notice, this cannot be done in Django.

Answer (score 2):

Improvement to @madprops answer - solution as a django management command:

```
import MySQLdb
from django.conf import settings

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        host = settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']
        password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
        user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
        dbname = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

        db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=dbname)
        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("ALTER DATABASE `%s` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'" % dbname)

        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(table_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '%s'" % dbname
        cursor.execute(sql)

        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            print(f'Changing table "{row[0]}"...')
            sql = "ALTER TABLE `%s` convert to character set DEFAULT COLLATE DEFAULT" % (row[0])
            cursor.execute(sql)
        db.close()
```

Hope this helps anybody but me :)

Comment: This line ```sql = "ALTER TABLE `%s` convert to character set DEFAULT COLLATE DEFAULT" % (row[0])``` should be changed to ```sql = "ALTER TABLE `%s` convert to character set 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' " % (row[0])``` . Thank you for very best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't trying to save unicode strings, you're trying to save bytestrings in the UTF-8 encoding. Make them actual unicode string literals:

```
user.last_name = u'Slatkevičius'
```

or (when you don't have string literals) decode them using the utf-8 encoding:

```
user.last_name = lastname.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @Thomas, i tried exactly as what you said but it still raise same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Simply alter your table, no need to any thing. just run this query on database.
***ALTER TABLE `table_name`CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8***

it will definately work.

Comment: Not straightforward:  Error Code: 1118. Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs . I can change it, but then Django will mess with it