# django loading fixtures fails on unicode data

Tags: mysql, django, unicode, django-fixtures

I saved a bunch of fixtures via dumpdata, here is an example:

```
[
  {
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "core.question",
    "fields": {
      "text": "\u041a\u0430\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u0436\u0438\u0432\u043e\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0432\u044b \u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u043e\u043c\u0430",
      "is_free_text": false
    }
  },
  {
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "core.question",
    "fields": {
      "text": "\u0415\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u043b\u0438 \u0432\u044b \u043c\u044f\u0441\u043e?",
      "is_free_text": false
    }
  },
  {
    "pk": 3,
    "model": "core.question",
    "fields": {
      "text": "\u041a\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u0435\u043d\u043e\u0442 \u0436\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u0443 \u0432\u0430\u0441 \u0434\u043e\u043c\u0430",
      "is_free_text": false
    }
  }
]
```

when I do

> manage.py loaddata core_question.json

, the following error comes up:

> Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x94\xD0\xB8\xD0\xB0...' for
>   column 'first_name' at row 1

I though it could be the database thing but it all seems to be unicode:

```
character_set_client,utf8
character_set_connection,utf8
character_set_database,utf8
character_set_filesystem,binary
character_set_results,utf8
character_set_server,utf8
character_set_system,utf8
character_sets_dir,/usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

as well as the schema collation:

> CATALOG_NAME,SCHEMA_NAME,DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME,DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME,SQL_PATH
>   NULL,reviewer,utf8,utf8_general_ci,NULL

is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Have you looked at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django