# Hibernate DataException on saving Č, Ć characters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, exception

As the title says, I'm using Hibernate ORM and whenever I try to save something with Č or Ć in it hibernate throws "couldn't execute query" error. I am using utf8, and Š, Ž, Đ characters work just fine. I'm lost...here is the cfg file:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventi_orm</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">false</property>
```

And here is the output:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x87' for column 'name' at row 1
```

Comment: "Data truncation" ... UTF-8 characters have variable length. BTW database (mysql) should be precisely configured, because of sorting and other problems. In ancient years we store utf-8 strigs in ASCII database columns, similar problem happens

Comment: I believe this is a same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL "incorrect string value" error when save unicode string in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django)

Comment: @Goran- Try to use a DB client and insert a string containing Č and Ć into your database. If the error is still present then it's mostly likely that your DB isn't configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, it was a silly oversight. I specified utf8 in a hibernate cfg file but forgot to do so when creating database.