# Encoding troubles with python, mysql and utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, character-encoding, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I get the following warnings, when trying to save a simple dataframe to mysql.:

> C:...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\x92\xE9t\xE9)' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 518")
>     result = self._query(query)

And

> C:...anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:170: Warning:
>   (3719, "'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3,
>   but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider
>   using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.")   result =
>   self._query(query)

Environment info : I use Mysql8, python3.6 (pymysql 0.9.2, sqlalchemy 1.2.1)

I visited posts like the one linked bellow, none of which seem to give a solution as to how to avoid this warning.

- [MySQL “incorrect string value” error when save unicode string in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django) -> Indication is to use UTF8

N.B : The Collation in the table within mysql doesn't seem to be set to the one I specified in the `create_db` function within the `Connection` class.

The executable code:

```
import DataEngine.db.Connection as connection
import random
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = connection.Connection(host="host_name", port="3306", user="username", password="password")
    conn.create_db("raw_data")
    conn.establish("raw_data")
    l1 = []
    for i in range(10):
        l_nested = []
        for j in range(10):
            l_nested.append(random.randint(0, 100))
        l1.append(l_nested)
    df = pd.DataFrame(l1)

    conn.save(df, "random_df")
    df2 = conn.retrieve("random_df")
    print(df2)
```

So the dataframe that is persisted in the database is :

```
   index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0      0  11  57  75  45  81  70  91  66  93  96
1      1  51  43   3  64   2   6  93   5  49  40
2      2  35  80  76  11  23  87  19  32  13  98
3      3  82  10  69  40  34  66  42  24  82  59
4      4  49  74  39  61  14  63  94  92  82  85
5      5  50  47  90  75  48  77  17  43   5  29
6      6  70  40  78  60  29  48  52  48  39  36
7      7  21  87  41  53  95   3  31  67  50  30
8      8  72  79  73  82  20  15  51  14  38  42
9      9  68  71  11  17  48  68  17  42  83  95
```

My `Connection class`

```
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql
import pandas as pd


class Connection:
    def __init__(self: object, host: str, port: str, user: str, password: str):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.conn = None

    def create_db(self: object, db_name: str, charset: str = "utf8mb4", collate:str ="utf8mb4_unicode_ci",drop_if_exists: bool = True):
        c = pymysql.connect(host=self.host, user=self.user, password=self.password)
        if drop_if_exists:
            c.cursor().execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " + db_name)
        c.cursor().execute("CREATE DATABASE " + db_name + " CHARACTER SET=" + charset + " COLLATE=" + collate)
        c.close()
        print("Database %s created with a %s charset" % (db_name, charset))

    def establish(self: object, db_name: str, charset: str = "utf8mb4"):
        self.conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            "mysql+pymysql://" + self.user + ":" + self.password + "@" + self.host + ":" + self.port + "/" + db_name +
            "?charset=" + charset)
        print("Connection with database : %s has been established as %s at %s." % (db_name, self.user, self.host))
        print("Charset : %s" % charset)

    def retrieve(self, table):
        df = pd.read_sql_table(table, self.conn)
        return df

    def save(self: object, df: "Pandas.DataFrame", table: str, if_exists: str = "replace", chunksize: int = 10000):
        df.to_sql(name=table, con=self.conn, if_exists=if_exists, chunksize=chunksize)
```

Some elements that might help:
[image: Database is of charset utf8mb4]
[image: Table columns don't seem to have the correct collation even though I specified it when creating the db]

Answer (score 1):

Well, hex 92 and e9 is not valid utf8mb4 (UTF-8).  Perhaps you were expecting `’été`, assuming `CHARACTER SETs` cp1250, cp1256, cp1257, or latin1.

Find out where that text is coming from, and let's decide whether it is valid `latin1`.  *Then* we can fix the code to declare that the client is really using latin1, not utf8mb4?  Or we can fix the client to use UTF-8, which would probably be better in the long run.

Comment: But there is no `éé`,  they're just numbers as shown in the main.

Comment: @Aetos - Is it in French, and talking about "summer"?

Comment: There are no characters at all in the dataset. If the data isn't in the dataset where else would it come from?

Comment: @Aetos - "column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 518" -- hmmmm...  Was this a fresh install of MySQL?  Or an Upgrade?  Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`  I'm wondering what is at line 518 of those.

Comment: This was a fresh install. I did a `mysql -u"UserName" -p -h "HOST" -A -e"SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;" > MySQLCurrentStatus.txt`, I got an output with 429 lines. As for `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` The line 518 contains `sync_relay_log_info 10000`.

Comment: As I understand from other posts with similar encoding issues (if that's the problem) `VARIABLE_VALUE` is a column name. Except I don't have any columns named that way, so perhaps it's a place holder or default column name related to sqlalchemy? See link : [bitbucket issue 4085](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/4085/warning-1366-incorrect-string-value) Please keep in mind my actual data contains just numbers, not characters or special characters.

Comment: @Aetos - The last comment on the bigbucket page refers to "stdin".  Do you know how that input was generated?  I can't think of a case where exactly `VARIABLE_VALUE` is used (I was mistakenly thinking that `SHOW` used that phrasing.)