# Save unicode pictograms to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8, collation

I have some code (at django server) that writes json data contained in POST requests into mysql db. 
Some requests contain specific pictograms like  or  .
Those are supposed to be written to a text field, but cause a db error.

Code processing the requests looks like

```
            json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
            i = Event(event=json_data['event'], dt=parse(json_data['dt']),
                      object_id=json_data['object_id'], user_id=json_data['user_id'],
                      payload=json_data['payload'])
            i.save()
```

db collation is currently set to uft8_general_ci.

Error returned is 'Incorrect string value'.

What is best practice to have such requests saved to the db along others?

**update**: By changing collation to utf8mb4_general_ci I can now write those symbols to db directly (via phpmyadmin) but still no luck with python request. Same error. Something on django side?

Comment: You will need to use UTF8MB4

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question.  We need to verify that the _column_ in question is `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MySQL charset to utf8mb4 will allow you to serialize the pictograms to the DB directly but in order to fix this on the Django end you will have to update your settings.py as well (see below):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
    } }
```

See also [MySQL “incorrect string value” error when save unicode string in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django)