# Incorrect string value error on inserting Unicode value alchemy

Tags: python, sql, unicode, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQL alchemy in python to connect with the SQL database. I am inserting a value "சிறார்கள்" in the form.

i receive this value as

```
editedProduct = dbsession.query(Product).filter_by(id=product_id).one()
othertitle = request.form.get('othertitle') 
editedProduct.othertitle = othertitle
dbsession.commit()
```

I receive this error .

> sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xAE\x9A\xE0\xAE\xBF...' for column 'othertitle' at row 1") [SQL: 'UPDATE product SET edition=%(edition)s, available_quantity=%(available_quantity)s, othertitle=%(othertitle)s, language=%(language)s, image_url=%(image_url)s, description=%(description)s, price=%(price)s, weight=%(weight)s WHERE product.id = %(product_id)s'] [parameters: {'price': '123.00', 'product_id': 1, 'weight': '1.0', 'edition': '121', 'available_quantity': '2', 'othertitle': 'சிறார்கள்', 'description': ' 9780132354615', 'image_url': '7e73c42e-82c5-47b2-aafa-d02c4b84b07f.jpg', 'language': ['English']}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)

My database url is

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@localhost:3306/bookstore?charset=utf8'.format(USR, PWD)
```

also tried charset as utf8mb4.

I found this type of question there. 
But it encodes and decodes, it gives unnecessary overhead. 
[MySQL "incorrect string value" error when save unicode string in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django)

Could you please suggest me a solution for this. When I try with the SQLite database I didn't get this error.

Comment: Did you actually alter the database/table/column charset to utf8mb4, or just change the connection string?

Comment: I alter database . ALTER DATABASE bookstore CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: You need to change the table too if it existed before you changed the db. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049958/6560549 to check table and column character sets (so you can confirm if you are actually writing to utf8mb4) and this blog post: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4 is a good step by step guide to transitioning.

Comment: Thanks not only changing the database didn't work. + Changing the all tables worked. thanks . @SuperShoot

Comment: Hey that’s great to hear!