# MySql C# Insert Error. Incorrect string value: '\xE1ra'

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using the C# .NET Mysql Connector, and when running this query:

```
INSERT INTO convos (`userid`,`time`,`from`,`content`,`read`,`deleted`, `ip`, `source`, `charname`, `to`) VALUES ('3', '1347396787', 'Chára', '........', '0', '0', '0.0.0.0:0000', 'C', 'óóóíííí', 'óóóíííí');
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect string value: '\xE1ra' for column 'from' at row 1

I understand my encoding, everything was configured for utf8, utf8_general_ci.  Database, table and columns are configured for utf8. The data is sent from the client in utf8.

If i use a 3rd party tool like, Workbench to insert the query or use the mysql command line it works fine. I don't know if there is a bug with the connector or i need to be doing something else with the values before insert?

Any idea?

Thanks

Is there any in mysql to covert to the correct type?

Comment: The `\xE1` implies your data is not being sent as UTF-8. How are you creating/processing the query?

Comment: Initially i am receiving the data from the client but for testing i am manually typing the query. So its like string = "INSERT INTO convos (`userid`,`time`,`from`,`content`,`read`,`deleted`, `ip`, `source`, `charname`, `to`) VALUES ('3', '1347396787', 'Chára', '........', '0', '0', '0.0.0.0:0000', 'C', 'óóóíííí', 'óóóíííí');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, its taken a while but it seems i was setting the charset too often. The database, tables, columns are all in UTF8. When i made a connection i had "CHARSET=UTF8" in the connection string. I was also running "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'" everytime i made a connection. I dropped the CHARSET=UTF8 and "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'" and its all working now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to alter the column's char set:

use below code for those columns which is using UTF-8.

```
ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)  
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, but all of the columns are already the correct character sets.

Answer (score 1):

[Unicode string prefix with N](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530)

First see your table convos and make sure columns data types is either one of nchar, nvarchar and You must precede all Unicode strings with a prefix N when you deal with Unicode string constants in SQL Server

Tyr:

```
    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO convos (`userid`,`time`,`from`,`content`,`read`,`deleted`, `ip`, `source`, `charname`, `to`) VALUES
 (N'3', N'1347396787', N'Chára', N'........', N'0', N'0', N'0.0.0.0:0000', N'C', N'óóóíííí', N'óóóíííí')";
```

Comment: Its for MYSQL, i don't think the same applies?

Answer (score 0):

Update it

```
INSERT INTO convos (`userid`,`time`,`from`,`content`,`read`,`deleted`, `ip`, `source`, `charname`, `to`) VALUES ('3', '1347396787', 'Chara', '........', '0', '0', '0.0.0.0:0000', 'C', 'óóóíííí', 'óóóíííí');
```

I think for "chara"in your 3rd value gives it

Answer (score 0):

For someone who has tried all the suggestions, and nothing has worked (like myself), it is worth checking what MySQL types are your fields mapped to in C#. My text fields were automatically mapped as **MySqlDbType.Blob** and that was causing the error. I changed the type to **MySqlDbType.Text**, and I don't see the error any more.

Here is my original response to a similar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989466/2199026

Answer (score 0):

config mysql like below. it will solve the unicode error when insert into mysql from java or C#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kp7A.png)

Comment: You should copy the text from the image and put it in code format instead. Read the SO guidelines before posting.