# MySQL Error 1366 Incorrect String Value

Tags: mysql, string

I have been looking everywhere for an answer, but I still have not found a solution.
Background:
I have a MySQL Server 5.5 running on my computer for testing data that will be eventually loaded into a Production Server for my company.  I created the database in MySQL Workbench and have edited it where appropriate to fit my data as I loaded it.  My data is nowhere near clean, so for the most part I am using VARCHAR for my fields, since a whole bunch of random things can be put into the field.  I have tried changing multiple things and I am no longer sure whether anything I have done has fixed or even helped to eliminate the issue at all.

My Code:
DB Creation:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

SET NAMES utf8;

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Customer_Account`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Customer_Account` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Customer_Account` (
  `idCustomer_Account` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(130) NOT NULL,
  `Billing_Street` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  `Billing_City` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Billing_StateProvince` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `Billing_PostalCode` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `Billing_Country` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Location_Type` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `Parent_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Parent_Name` VARCHAR(130) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCustomer_Account`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idCustomer_Account_UNIQUE` (`idCustomer_Account` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  'CONSTRAINT `Parent_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCustomer_Account`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Customer_Account` (`idCustomer_Account`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)'

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Customer_Address`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Customer_Address` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Customer_Address` (
  `idCustomer_Address` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Name_Int` INT,
  `Address` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `State` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `ZIP` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `LinkedAccount_Name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `LinkedAccount_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `CADD` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCustomer_Address`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idCustomer_Address_UNIQUE` (`idCustomer_Address` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Contacts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Contacts` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Contacts` (
  `idContacts` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Title` VARCHAR(130) NULL,
  `Mailing_Street` VARCHAR(110) NULL,
  `Mailing_City` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Mailing_State` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `Mailing_PostalCode` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Phone` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Account_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Account_Name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idContacts`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idContacts_UNIQUE` (`idContacts` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Contact_Details`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`Contact_Details` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Contact_Details` (
  `idContact_Details` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Salutation` VARCHAR(70) NULL,
  `First_Name` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Last_Name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Title` VARCHAR(130) NULL,
  `Mailing_Street` VARCHAR(175) NULL,
  `Mailing_City` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Mailing_StateProvince` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Mailing_PostalCode` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Mailing_Country` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `Phone` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Mobile` VARCHAR(35) NULL,
  `Fax` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(75) NULL,
  `Email_OptOut` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `Account_Owner` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Account_Name` VARCHAR(125) NULL,
  `Account_ID` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Active` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idContact_Details`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idContact_Details_UNIQUE` (`idContact_Details` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

'INDEX `Account_ID_idx` (`Account_ID` ASC)'

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`WF1_SR_Accounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`WF1_SR_Accounts` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`WF1_SR_Accounts` (
  `idWF1_SR_Accounts` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL,
  `Billing_Street` VARCHAR(135) NULL,
  `Billing_City` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `Billing_State` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Billing_PostalCode` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Billing_Country` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `Location_Type` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Parent_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Parent_Name` VARCHAR(125) NULL,
  `SR_Account?` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `WF1_Account?` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `WF1_AccountNum` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `WF1_AccountStatus` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `WF1_AccountCreated` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `WF1_BU` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `WF1_Collector` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `WF1_CreditHold` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `WF1_CreditLimit` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `WF1_CreditRating` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `WF1_DVP` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `WF1_PaymentTerms` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `WF1_RSD` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `WF1_TerritoryName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `WF1_TerritoryNumber` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `Select_` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `New_Select` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `CRMFusion_Use` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `CRMFusion_Change` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idWF1_SR_Accounts`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idWF1_SR_Accounts_UNIQUE` (`idWF1_SR_Accounts` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Note: I have also substituted latin1 for utf8 in SET NAMES, DEFUALT CHARSET, and CHARACTER_SET_SERVER, and tried to make my .txt files of both encryption types.

I also ran

```
SHOW VARIABLES like 'char%';
```

and this is my result:

```
Variable_name                   Value
character_set_client            latin1
character_set_connection            latin1
character_set_database          utf8
character_set_filesystem            binary
character_set_results           latin1
character_set_server            latin1
character_set_system            utf8
character_sets_dir            C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\share\charsets\
```

Note: at one point, everything but filesystem and server were utf8 and it did not work either.

I have also changed the encryption type in excel and notepad++ and changing that did not seem to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Answer (score -1):

The primary Key need to be changed from INT to VARCHAR(45) data types.