# Why won't my MySQL insert work on PHP when it contains a ® character?

Tags: php, mysql

First as a side note, I am using the old deprecated `mysql_query`, but at this point I am unable to vastly change my code yet.

OK when I try to do an INSERT with a ® character in it through PHP (coming from a form POST), I'm getting a failure with this code and the insert doesn't happen:

```
$insert_title = "
    INSERT INTO pin (
        title, 
        front
    ) VALUES (
        '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['pintitle'])."', 
        '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['pinfront'])."'
    )";
```

But when I paste this into MySQL Workbench and execute the statement it does the insert just fine:

```
INSERT INTO pin ( title, front ) 
VALUES ( 'test', '®' )
```

What am I doing wrong on the PHP side?

Here is what `mysql_error()` is showing me:

```
1366: Incorrect string value: '\xAE' for column 'front' at row 1
```

Comment: Are you checking for errors using `mysql_error()` after the query? Also [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: `var_dump($insert_title);`

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Just updated my question with the `mysql_error()` return

Comment: What collation is your table?

Comment: @EthanAllen Are you sure, that mysql_escape_string produces the correct result for ® symbol? It looks suspicious, that the same symbol works with Workbench.

Comment: Several possible answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors

Comment: It's most likely a collation problem. Either the input is UTF-8 and the connection isn't, or the other way round.

Comment: Just set your collation to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: @deadlock It already is `utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was that I wasn't properly UTF-8 encoding on the website side (PHP in my case). I just added this and it was solved:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

?>
```

Comment: Just to point out this has nothing to do with how PHP is handling the data but rather it is telling the browser submitting the form to use UTF8. Also as another point, this won't fix the problem in older versions of IE

Comment: Is there a solution for older IE versions?