# MySql: Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9Fe' for column

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, utf-8

I have a stored procedure and it has a string parameter. When I call with word which contains some special chars like 'ş' or 'ğ' it returns `Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x9Fe' for column 'personalNames' at row 1 . But when I call with without this special chars everything is ok.`

Here is my a part of my sp :

```
IF personalNames != '' THEN
    SET personalNames = LOWER(personalNames);
    SET @WherePart = CONCAT(@WherePart,' AND LOWER(per.Name) LIKE "%',personalNames,'%"');
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11013986/1745672

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was on the parameters. I changed my parameter to `personalNames  VARCHAR(200) character set utf8` and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the charset of the Database. Change it to UTF-8. This can be done on the commandline if you start mysql-Server.
The parameter is:

```
--default-character-set=UTF8
```

Regards 
Marc