# Mysql encoding error

Tags: mysql, node.js, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to insert a row in mysql from node using [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) driver, and I am getting the following error:

```
running query \"INSERT INTO outgo (name, monthIdMonth, type, distribution, recurrent, amount) VALUES ('Penalizări', (select MAX(idMonth) from `month`), '3', '1', '1', '0');\"
failed: Error: Incorrect string value: '\\xC4\\x83ri' for column 'name' at row 1
```

The outgo table is created like this:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `outgo` (
  `idOutgo` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `apartmentsGroupIdApartmentsGroup` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `outgoColumnInfoIdOutgoColumn` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `metering` ENUM('NONE','COLD_WATER','HOT_WATER','OTHER') NULL,
  `distribution` ENUM('MANUAL','PERSON','APARTMENT','SURFACE','CONSUMPTION', 'AUTOMATED','HEAT_SURFACE') NULL,
  `amount` DOUBLE(14,2) NULL,
  `cAmount` DOUBLE(14,2) NULL,
  `costPerUnit` DOUBLE(15,3) NULL,
  `unit` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `quantity` DOUBLE(14,2) NULL,
  `diffs` DOUBLE(14,4) NULL,
  `recurrent` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `monthIdMonth` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('GENERAL','REMAINING','PENALITY') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'GENERAL',
  `billIdBill` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Any idea what the problem is? The string it is complaining about is: "Penalizări".
Schema encoding is utf8....

Comment: Show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the `outgo`. And what is the connection encoding?

Comment: I do not specify a connection encoding. How could I find out? Is it what "locale" command return on linux?

Comment: can you show the code used to insert row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Comment: Are you trying to use `ă`?  Its utf8 hex is C483.  A guess:  You have not specified [utf8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279)

Answer (score 4):

So, in the end, I found the solution: I added a charset parameter to the node connection:

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : config.get.mysql.host,
    port     : config.get.mysql.port,
    user     : config.get.mysql.username,
    password : config.get.mysql.password,
    database : 'general',
    connectionLimit : 50,
    queueLimit : 5000,
    charset: "utf8_general_ci"
});
```