# How to import greek data into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to Insert Greek data on my phpmyadmin database, but when I execute my query, I get the following error message:

*Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xCE\x9A\xCE\xB7\xCF\x82' for column 'description' at row 1*

My table uses **utf8_general_ci** collation.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)?

Comment: column collation is utf8 and what about table collate?

Comment: There is no such thing as phpmyadmin database. Your database is in mysql, phpmyadmin simply manages the databases in your mysql server.

Comment: Have you checked the default character set of your connection? Here is how to check character sets in use : http://makandracards.com/makandra/2529-show-and-change-mysql-default-character-set Here shows how to set the connection character set : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: Ok problem solved. I actually used the query SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'; and I noticed that the collation was not right for the VARCHARS. So I switched a VARCHAR variable to utf8_general_ci. 
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I assume you were expecting `Κης`.