# MySQL warning: Incorrect string value: '\x96

Tags: mysql, utf-8, warnings, utf8mb4

I'm trying to import a CVS file where I get this warning: 
1366 Incorrect string value: '\x96 PART...' for column

I read somewhere that this is about the 4-bit utf8 characters. But changing the collation of the table and column into utf8mb4 didn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Comment: How are you importing the file exactly? What encoding is the file in? What is the **connection encoding** to your database?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes, I saw that question and answer, but I also noticed that there is an argument that the mentioned method changes the database itself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11013986/3316750

Comment: @deceze, I do not know the answer to those questions. I'm searching know to figure out how I can learn the encoding of a CSV file and the database connection encoding.

Answer (score 4):

The hex `96` is presumably the `latin1` encoding for an `en-dash` (`–`).  But you have specified that the CSV file is utf8-encoded (or utf8mb4), this character is incomprehensible to utf8.

Plan A:  Change the file.  (This is probably not practical.)

Plan B:  Tell MySQL that the file is latin1 (as opposed to utf8).  Then MySQL will convert it correctly to the utf8-encoding `E28093`.

"Collation" has to do with sorting and comparing; "Character set" has to do with 'encoding'.

Add this to the `LOAD DATA` statement that I assume you are using:

```
CHARACTER SET latin1
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).