# Try add ascii literals

Tags: python, django

Have a csv file with data. do parse that.

```
        file_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in file_reader:
        data = UserDataCsv()
        data.user = files.user
        data.file_hash = request.FILES['file']
        data.file = UserFiles.objects.get(id=file_id)

        print(row[0])


        data.material = row[0]
```

But when i try add new row got error.

> ```
> Internal Server Error: /upload_file/
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> ```
>
> line 42, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>       File "D:\PythoProjecs\csv_files\users\user_functions.py", line 112, in upload_file
>       data.save()
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 796, in save
>       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 824, in save_base
>       updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>        File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _save_table
>       result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
>       using=using, raw=raw)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1045, in _insert
>       return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line
>   1054, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
>       return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line
>   110, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorclass,
>   errorvalueOperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value:
>   '\xC4\xD1\xCF' for column 'material' at row 1") [30/Jun/2017
>   16:34:32] "POST /upload_file/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17454

How i can fix that?

Comment: Are you trying to add a row to your DB trough django ORM ? Can you show us the request ?

Comment: And what is the table charset ?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors

Comment: users_userdatacsv   InnoDB utf8_general_ci 48

Comment: do             `e = row[0].decode("utf-8") print(e)` in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
[30/Jun/2017 17:19:49] "POST /upload_file/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15507