# Zabbix 3.4 installation error-->database error-->create.sql script error

Tags: mysql, zabbix

When run the following command:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.4.1/create.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p zabbix
```

it shows the following error:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000) at line 3390: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA1'
>   for column 'units' at row 1

[image: Screenshot]

**How can this be resolved?**

Comment: Which distribution, which package is that ?

Comment: Sir it is-->repo-->rpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.4-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm<br>yum -y install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql

Comment: i had resolved this issue by changing my database setting UTF-8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this issue by changing my database setting UTF-8.

Help Tag:
[How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors?answertab=active#tab-top)