# MySQL incorrect string value error on MySQL 5.7 but not on 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

In a PHP application I'm trying to save the content of an email on the database (table is utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_general_ci). When doing tests on my dev enviroment it works fine but on productions I keep getting errors like this one:

```
General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC7ALHO-...' for column 'content_html' at row 1
```

I checked and I realized I had MySQL 5.5 on dev and 5.7 on prod, I upgraded mysql on my dev and now I get the error on dev as well.
The problem is I don't understand why I'm getting this errors, the content is a very standard email with nothing much but a header logo.
Any idea why this is failing on 5.7 and not in 5.5 and if there's any workaround on this?

Update: here's the SHOW FULL COLUMNS of the table

```
ysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM received_email;
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field           | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id              | int(11)      | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| skill_id        | int(11)      | NULL               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| agent_id        | int(11)      | NULL               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| message_id      | longtext     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| received_date   | datetime     | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| downloaded_date | datetime     | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| from_name       | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| from_email      | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| subject         | longtext     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| content_html    | longtext     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| content_plain   | longtext     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| recipient       | varchar(255) | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| created_at      | datetime     | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| updated_at      | datetime     | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| case_detail_id  | int(11)      | NULL               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-----------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicated [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Comment: what's the character_set for that specific column? run this `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;` and past the output.

Comment: @Ali added to the descritption, its all utf8mb4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that are 2 things that you can check...

1) email content charset

- what is the email content charset... utf-8 too?
- if not, did you tried to convert it to utf-8?

2) sql mode - there are some default changes from MySql 5.5 to 5.7

more info you can find :
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html
- https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-disable-strict-mode-in-mysql-5-7.html

Comment: Disabling the stric mode as pointed on serverpilot worked for me!

Comment: @petekaner the only problem with that is the fact that the server with strict SQL mode *enabled* is the one that is *correct*.  The data is invalid and you're masking the real problem (and the column may in fact be blank).  `0xC7` is not a valid character representation in utf8, but it's the latin1 representation of `Ç`.  The problem is in your code, not your server.

Answer (score 0):

State that your *client* has `latin1` bytes.  Do this in the connection string, or right afterwards via `SET NAMES latin1`.

MySQL will convert the `C7` to the utf8 equivalent "on the wire".

Do not use any conversion functions, that is likely to only make things worse, or at least harder to unravel.