# InternalError: 1366

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to making a web crawler for a schoolproject. When i try to scrape some websites, i get the following error:

> Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x82\xC5\xA4 \xC3...' for column
>   'content' at row 1

The configuration for the table content looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scotchbox.content (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  url INT(11) NOT NULL,
  content LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  content_raw LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  content_raw_hash VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX idx_content__url (url ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_content__url
    FOREIGN KEY (url)
    REFERENCES scotchbox.url (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 4
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
```

Can anyone tell me what i need to change/do to get page into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will help you to fix your problem from a previous question.

[How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)