# Insertion error in MySQL database using python package pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

Here is my code for insertion.

```
myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO news_table(news_title, news_source, news_link, news_img, news_date, news_view, news_text, news_hit) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(nextntitle, nextnsource, nextnlink, nextnimg, nextndate, nextntext))
```

my database name is news_table which has 9 attributes, but when i am trying to insert the data with the code it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/qasys/PycharmProjects/conda_main/pythonmysql/checkdb.py", line 82, in <module>
    myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO news_table(news_title, news_source, news_link, news_img, news_date, news_view, news_text, news_hit) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);",(nextntitle, nextnsource, nextnlink, nextnimg, nextndate, nextntext))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1066, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\conda_main\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

i am using mysql with python for the first time. Can anyone provide some help about the issue.
NB: I have no database connection error or package installation error problem.

Comment: @sorav I have edited my answer based on your question.

Comment: @Er_sherlockian check your answer's comment section

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
(news_title, news_source, news_link, news_img, news_date, news_view, news_text, news_hit) 
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

There are more fields in the destination columns than %s in your VALUES(...)

you MUST supply a value for each destination column

Comment: [link](https://ideone.com/g5i51r)
new problem have arisen & sorry for the last problem as undoing is not noticed before posting the question.
&
i already have converted the string need to be sent to the database with default str() function for safe case. but still the problem arises.

Comment: @sourav sorry. Please include ALL the relevant info IN your question. The idea is to keep the solution (whatever it is) for everyone, here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". Number of columns doesn't match your %s

It should be

```
myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO news_table(news_title, news_source, news_link, news_img, news_date, news_view, news_text, news_hit) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,0,%s,0);",(nextntitle, nextnsource, nextnlink, nextnimg, nextndate, nextntext))
```

After removing **news_view** and **news_hit**

OR

```
myCursor.execute("INSERT INTO news_table(news_title, news_source, news_link, news_img, news_date, news_view, news_text, news_hit) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,0,%s,0);",(nextntitle, nextnsource, nextnlink, nextnimg, nextndate, nextntext))
```

After adding default values 0 for **news_view** and **news_hit**

Comment: [link](https://ideone.com/g5i51r)
new problem have arisen & sorry for the last problem as undoing is not noticed before posting the question.

Comment: i already have converted the string need to be sent to the database with default str() function for safe case. but still the problem arises.

Comment: Look at this for that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors/24559308