# How can I fix "1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE5'

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, utf8mb4

I checked other topics and changed my database to this "utf8mb4_general_ci" and also I am trying to insert data with laravel thats why I changed laravel Mysql Database config to this;

'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',

but still when I try to migrate data to database table still this error pops up.

Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE5' for column 'Addresses' at row 1")

What am I missing here? Also i am trying to add Japanese Text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Incorrect string value" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors)

Comment: Actually I checked that page and do that stuff for example changing Database general_ci etc. but couldn't solve the problem. I think I need mych more specific answer for this. Very newbie at this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this little change can help you

```
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Comment: still same error; PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE5' for column 'Addresses' at row 1")