# "incorrect string value" but can decode with UTF-8

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to MySQL and am writing text data to a database and get this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xCC\xB5#821...' for column 'column' at row 1
```

But when I decode that text in Python, it doesn't throw any errors:

```
In: b'\xCC\xB5#821...'.decode('utf-8')
Out: '̵#821...'
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168036/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-errors) seems to indicate that this code would throw an error, but it's not.
What am I missing?

Comment: Is that a three-byte or four-byte value? MySQL requires `utf8mb4` for those.

Comment: @tadman I regret to say that I'm not sure what that means :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware that the default character set is not actually UTF-8. Using `ALTER TABLE <table> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, as indicated by other answers, fixed the problem.