# 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x89lise' for column (only first byte/first character)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a new record to my MySQL table but I'm getting the following error:

`An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO team_mate (id, first_name, cached_sessions_count, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
with params ["\xb6\xc4\xcf\x4e\x19\xcc\x43\x04\x82\x63\x79\x31\xec\x21\x5e\x66", "\x3f\x89\x6c\x69\x73\x65", 0, "2019-10-28 20:11:42", "2019-10-28 20:11:42"]:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x89lise' for column 'first_name' at row 1`

What is very weird is that inserting a new record named **Élise** doesn't work (and produces this error), but inserting **aÉlise** does work, in fact the error only happens when the first byte or first character of the field contains an accentued character.

Setup :

- I use MySQL 8.0.18
- I connect to my database using charset `utf8mb4`
- The table `team_mate` has collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
- The field `first_name` in my table has collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

The result of `show variables like '%colla%';` performed from the connection:

```
collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The result of `show variables like '%charac%';` performed from the connection:

```
character_set_client = utf8mb4
character_set_connection = utf8mb4
character_set_database = utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem = binary
character_set_results = utf8mb4
character_set_server = utf8mb4
character_set_system = utf8
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might need to check your table collation. Otherwise these articles may help you sort this all out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11013986/5749464 (use utf8mb4 instead of utf8)  and https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: Hello, thanks, I have checked both articles and then my connection/database/table/field settings and everything seems in order, here is what I have:

collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

character_set_client = utf8mb4
character_set_connection = utf8mb4
character_set_database = utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem = binary
character_set_results = utf8mb4
character_set_server = utf8mb4
character_set_system = utf8

Also, both the database collation and table collation are utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't mysql, but the app that is executing your insert query for you.

Comment: That's an interesting point! When I try to do the same query using PhpMyAdmin:

`INSERT INTO team_mate (id, first_name, cached_sessions_count, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES (0xb6c4cf4e19cc430482637931ec215e66, 0x3f896c697365, 0, "2019-10-28 20:11:42", "2019-10-28 20:11:42")`

It fails with the same error... but if I do this one using the string values and not the binary ones:

`INSERT INTO team_mate (id, first_name, cached_sessions_count, created_at, updated_at)
VALUES (0xb6c4cf4e19cc430482637931ec215e66, "Élise", 0, "2019-10-28 20:11:42", "2019-10-28 20:11:42")`
It works normally

Comment: Indeed, you were right Ayrton. I'm using Symfony 4.2 with Doctrine standard implementation and it appears that when the first character of the string chain is accentuated, Doctrine considers the full field as binary and sends it as binary to MySQL.
However if I try to send "eÉlise", Doctrine sends it as a string and it works.
Why does it do that, I don't know yet, but it's not a MySQL question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind, I shouldn't have blamed Symfony/Doctrine/MySQL... After some debugging, I discovered that I had this function in the code:

```
public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
{
    $this->firstName = mb_strtoupper(substr($firstName, 0, 1)).substr($firstName, 1);
}
```

It was supposed to uppercase the first character, but because the first character extends over more than one byte, this creates wrong bytes that prevent the insertion in the database. I replaced `substr` by `mb_substr` and everything was working smoothly then!

Problem solved, thanks Ayrton!